# SAP Field Glass Integration for job pulling

Tags: sap

Am trying to pull jobs from SAPField Glass using the following endpoint;
https://sandbox.api.sap.com/fieldglass/job-openings/v1/job-openings?status=POSTED

1. Where can I find the Sandbox environment URL?
2. How can I obtain Dashboard access?
3. Where can we get the client ID and client secret for production, and how can we configure a new environment?
4. I am unable to log in to https://www.fieldglass.net/. I receive an error message stating, "The username or password is incorrect. In order to recover a username or reset a password, the Digital Assistant can help. If additional assistance is needed, contact your company administrator for help. Workers may contact their supervisor or staffing agency for assistance." Who can provide me with access to log in?
5. Could the following issue be due to the Sandbox environment URL?
   "{
   "fault": {
   "faultstring": "Unable to route the message to a Target Endpoint",
   "detail": {
   "errorcode": "messaging.runtime.RouteFailed"
   }
   }"

The jobs created via SAP Fieldglass Tryout API in the sandbox environment will only be visible within the sandbox environment?

To view the jobs, we need to log in to the SAP Fieldglass sandbox environment?

In order to get all these, we need to contact SAP field glass representative(Who will be this?).